# Использование toString с вложенными структурами

Tags: java

Допустим мы имеем `Map<Integer, Integer[]>` и нам надо воспользоваться toString.

Тут и проблема: нам возвращают совсем не ту строку, что можно ожидать.

Например:

```
Map<Integer, Integer[]> mp = new HashMap<Integer, Integer[]>();
mp.put(1, new Integer[]{1, 2});
mp.put(2, new Integer[]{2, 3});
mp.put(3, new Integer[]{3, 4});

out.println(mp.toString());
```

Так нам выводит `{1=[Ljava.lang.Integer;@7852e922, 2=[Ljava.lang.Integer;@4e25154f, 3=[Ljava.lang.Integer;@70dea4e}` вместо  более ожидаемого `{1=[1, 2], 2=[2, 3], 3=[3, 4]}`. И вроде как логично, но совсем не то что нам надо.

Что делать, чтобы получить что хочется? Явно есть решение, которое не есть обработка структуры вручную.

Comment: Как например в python. На вывод структуры он отвечает красивой понятной строкой.

Answer (score 1):

К сожалению, в Java у массивов примитивных типов не переопределён метод `toString`. Поэтому к ним применяется метод, содержащийся в классе `Object`. Этот метод, конечно, не знает, как нужно выводить массивы. Однако специальный метод для этого есть в классе `Arrays`. Поэтому вы можете создать свой класс, который будет содержать массив целых чисел с переопределённым методом `toString`.

Например, вот [так](https://ideone.com/Qgk3k8):

```
class Ideone
{
    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
    {
        Map<Integer, IntegerArray> mp = new HashMap<Integer, IntegerArray>();
        mp.put(1, new IntegerArray(1, 2));
        mp.put(2, new IntegerArray(2, 3));
        mp.put(3, new IntegerArray(3, 4));

        System.out.println(mp);
    }
}

class IntegerArray {
    int[] array;

    IntegerArray(int... array){
        this.array = array;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString(){
        return Arrays.toString(array);
    }
}
```

Вывод будет:

```
{1=[1, 2], 2=[2, 3], 3=[3, 4]}
```

Answer (score 1):

В Java `toString` для массивов не выводит их значения, а всего лишь показывает объект в текстовом представлении. Для получения значений массива нужно воспользоваться методом `toString` класса `Arrays`. Соответственно, для вашего примера достаточно:

```
for(Map.Entry<Integer,Integer[] > entry : mp.entrySet())
{
     System.out.print(entry.getKey());
     System.out.println(Arrays.toString(entry.getValue()));
}
```